# How to set env values for eshell in emacs on macOS?

Tags: osx, terminal-emacs, eshell, environment, path

If use `iTerm` on macOS, we can set env values in its terminal. It also set path such as `/usr/local/bin/` in `~/.bashrc`.

But in emacs' terminal as `eshell`, run `kubectl` shown `kubectl: No such file or directory`.
It seems that it didn't find the command's path.

How to set path for emacs? For example, in `spacemacs`.

I found this [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)

```
M-x package-install exec-path-from-shell RET
```

Edit `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to add

```
(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

to the bottom.

Copy `PATH` from `.bashrc` to `.profile`.

```
$ cat ~/.profile
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

Start [GNU Emacs For Max OS X](https://emacsformacosx.com/) still can't find the command's path in eshell. The `spacemacs` alert:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading ‘/Users/user/.emacs.d/init.el’:

Symbol's function definition is void: exec-path-from-shell-initialize

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the ‘--debug-init’ option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

The full file of `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
;;; init.el --- Spacemacs Initialization File -*- no-byte-compile: t -*-
;;
;; Copyright (c) 2012-2020 Sylvain Benner & Contributors
;;
;; Author: Sylvain Benner <sylvain.benner@gmail.com>
;; URL: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs
;;
;; This file is not part of GNU Emacs.
;;
;;; License: GPLv3

;; Without this comment emacs25 adds (package-initialize) here
;; (package-initialize)

;; Avoid garbage collection during startup.
;; see `SPC h . dotspacemacs-gc-cons' for more info
(defconst emacs-start-time (current-time))
(setq gc-cons-threshold 402653184 gc-cons-percentage 0.6)
(load (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name)
              "core/core-versions.el")
      nil (not init-file-debug))
(load (concat (file-name-directory load-file-name)
              "core/core-load-paths.el")
      nil (not init-file-debug))
(load (concat spacemacs-core-directory "core-dumper.el")
      nil (not init-file-debug))

;; Clean compiled files if they become stale or Emacs version has changed.
(load (concat spacemacs-core-directory "core-compilation.el")
      nil (not init-file-debug))
(load spacemacs--last-emacs-version-file t (not init-file-debug))
(let ((default-directory spacemacs-start-directory))
  (when (or (not (string= spacemacs--last-emacs-version emacs-version))
            (spacemacs//contains-newer-than-byte-compiled-p
             spacemacs--compiled-files))
    (spacemacs//remove-byte-compiled-files spacemacs--compiled-files)))
(when (not (string= spacemacs--last-emacs-version emacs-version))
  (spacemacs//update-last-emacs-version))

(if (not (version<= spacemacs-emacs-min-version emacs-version))
    (error (concat "Your version of Emacs (%s) is too old. "
                   "Spacemacs requires Emacs version %s or above.")
           emacs-version spacemacs-emacs-min-version)
  ;; Disable file-name-handlers for a speed boost during init
  (let ((file-name-handler-alist nil))
    (require 'core-spacemacs)
    (spacemacs/dump-restore-load-path)
    (configuration-layer/load-lock-file)
    (spacemacs/init)
    (configuration-layer/stable-elpa-init)
    (configuration-layer/load)
    (spacemacs-buffer/display-startup-note)
    (spacemacs/setup-startup-hook)
    (spacemacs/dump-eval-delayed-functions)
    (when (and dotspacemacs-enable-server (not (spacemacs-is-dumping-p)))
      (require 'server)
      (when dotspacemacs-server-socket-dir
        (setq server-socket-dir dotspacemacs-server-socket-dir))
      (unless (server-running-p)
        (message "Starting a server...")
        (server-start)))))

(when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init file `~/.emacs.d/init.el` seems to be at the wrong place. It's better be at the **home folder** which is `~/`

Besides, the code to inject the `PATH` contents into emacs seems wrong. So, comment them out and try adding the following into the `~/.emacs` which is the most conventional init file for emacs and change `~/.bash_profile` to whatever you use as the bash init file (in your case it seems to be `/.bashrc`) and then of course restart the emacs.

```lisp
(let ((path (shell-command-to-string ". ~/.bash_profile; echo -n $PATH")))
  ;;  the dot . makes it execute the ~/bash_profile
  ;; echo -n $PATH prints out the PATH contents
  (setenv "PATH" path)
  (setq exec-path 
    (append
     (split-string-and-unquote path ":")
     exec-path)))
```

Furthermore, first try it with the `M-x shell` not the `eshell`
because `eshell` is an extra feature not essential.

Comment: Can you give us a link to a source in support of the proposition that the `init.el` must be in the **home folder**?  In addition, how does your answer resolve the error message reported by the O.P.?: "*Symbol's function definition is void:  `exec-path-from-shell-initialize`*"

Comment: `.emacs` being in the home folder is not a must but a usual preference (edited the post) The answer apparently doesn't resolve the error message, it just solves setting the env values for the `shell` (no guarantees for the `eshell`)